# How do I access my wireless access point via browser?

Tags: browser, home-networking, wireless-access-point, ipconfig

Here's my situation:

The home network is

wall <--pluged in modem/router <-- plugged in wireless DD-WRT router via 2 metre CAT5 cable<--- plugged in wireless belkin router, via 10 metre CAT5 cable.

The belkin router is used to extend access to the sleep out I live in.

I occasionally have some kind of network issue, where I have limited connectivity and can't access the internet. Solution seems to be to reset the belken access point. Problem is, the router is housed in my flatmates room, which is usually locked, so I'd like to reset it via browser.

if I do ipconfig, the default gateway shows the IP address of the DR-WRT router, and I can access it fine with my browser.

How can I access the belkin router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following:

1. - RouterA: Connected directly to the modem.
2. - RouterA: 192.168.0.1 Static IP LAN
3. - Router A: Configured for DHCP 192.168.0.0
4. - RouterB: Static LAN IP 192.168.0.2
5. - Router B: DHCP Disabled
6. - Router B: Connected to a LAN port on RouterA

From up PC, you can access the router from the IPs 1 and 2.

Comment: How would I configure router B? Would I have to plugin with an ethernet cable?

Comment: Exactly, you must configure RouterB using UTP cable using a computer before connecting to the network